# How to count elements between two values in sorted list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, binary-search, lower-bound

I have a `sorted list`. For example, `my list` is:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Actually, I have list of objects of my class with `int property`, on which the list is sorted.

I want to calculate number of objects, which have value of `this property` between `two values`.

I looking for the following python equivalent.

```
int main () {
  int myints[] = {10,20,30,30,20,10,10,20};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+8);           // 10 20 30 30 20 10 10 20

  std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());                // 10 10 10 20 20 20 30 30

  std::vector<int>::iterator low,up;
  low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); //          ^
  up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); //                   ^

  std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << '\n';

  std::cout << "MY_RESULT IS" << (up - v.begin())  - (low- v.begin()) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Elizion, Does slise copy objects?

Comment: it copies references.

Comment: Slicing won't work, as if refers to member index in list, not property value. What about `len([i for i in my_list if low < i.property < high])`?

Comment: @Nsh Right, misread the question my bad.

Comment: something like `lst.sort(); lst[lst.index(min(lst)):lst.index(max(lst))]` (haven't looked up what `lower_bound` does, but you can write a function similar to max that does something similar.

Comment: Do you want a newlist with values between two values like this? `newlist = [x for x in my_list if  3 < x < 10]`

Comment: @Nsh, but you way has `O(n)` Asymptotic, not `O(log(n))`, am I right?

Comment: @Elizion, I looking solution in `O(log(n))`, and I would not like copy objects. I want just calculate them.

Comment: very easy write your own bisection search based on the attribute value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `bisect` module (*as it uses binary search, giving it a O(log n) complexity)* to take a bisection of both sides, like so:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

import bisect

def find_ge(a, low, high):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(a, low)
    g = bisect.bisect_right(a, high)
    if i != len(a) and g != len(a):
        return a[i:g]
    raise ValueError
```

***Output***:

```
>>>find_ge(my_list, 3, 6)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: yeah, I use similar code too. But I thought, that It is non pythonic way.

Comment: The `bisect` module is a great option actually.

Comment: Why is that condition? ? Like this my last item of the list isnt shown

`>>find_ge (my_list, 10,10)
ValueError`

Comment: I think `and` in `if i != len(a) and g != len(a):` should be replaced with `or`. Otherwise, `valueError` will be raised if the range includes the last index value.